# Set token in Nuxt auth-module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I'm developing with [Nuxt auth-module](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/). Login API returns data in this structure:

```
data:{
    data:{
        user:{
        bio: null
        createdAt: "2021-06-29T12:28:42.442Z"
        email: "name@info.co"
        id: 1
        image: null
        token: "token"
        updatedAt: "2021-06-29T12:28:42.447Z"
        username: "name"
        }
     }
}
```

nuxtconfig:

```
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: 'users/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'data.user.token' },
          user: { url: 'me', method: 'get', propertyName: 'data' },
          logout: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

But the token does not save in the app. Do you have any solution?

**so I found a solution:**

```
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          property: 'user.token', // /user endpoint API returns user object
          type: 'Token' // if your token type is not Bearer
        },
        user: {
          user: 'user'
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/users/login', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: '/user', method: 'get' },
          logout: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure is `data.data.user` and not `data.user`, hence IMO you'll need to specify it with a configuration like this one

```js
auth: {
  strategies: {
    local: {
      user: {
        property: 'data.user', // or maybe 'data.data.user'
        // autoFetch: true
      },
    }
  }
}
```

As explained in the [documentation](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/local/#options).